# Javascript maximum call stack size even though recursive function call itself with an accumulator

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, callstack, tail-call-optimization

I have an object whose value can be any type.

```
  const data = {
    a: { aa: 50, ab: 'hello', ac: 'xx_1' },
    b: 50,
    c: [
      { ca: 100, cb: 'by', cc: 'xx_2' },
      { ca: 101, cb: 'by1', cc: 'xx_3' },
    ],
    d: [],
    e: {
      ea: 50,
      eb: ['xx_1', 'xx_4'],
    },
}
```

I need to browse through it and replace values that match with specific pattern.
To do that I use a recursive function (exportContractFormatter) and to replace the values I use a non-recursive function (exportContractConverter). To avoid maximum call stack size I use an accumulator (acc) when I do the recursive call.
To update the accumulator, I use lodash (update) method, based on the path.

```
export function exportContractFormatter(
  data: any[],
  exportContractConverter: (data:any, path:string[])=>any,
  acc: Record<string, any> = {},
  path: string[] = [],
  level = [] as number[]
): any {

  if (data.length === 0) return acc;
  const head = data[0];
  const tail = data.slice(1);

  // enter only if not empty array or not empty object
  if (
    typeof head[1] === 'object' &&
    head[1] !== null &&
    ((Array.isArray(head[1]) && head[1].length > 0) ||
      (!Array.isArray(head[1]) && Object.keys(head[1]).length > 0))
  ) {
    //if array use index as key
    const valueFormatted = Array.isArray(head[1])
      ? head[1].map((item, index) => [index, item])
      : Object.entries(head[1]);

    //initialize object or array thank to path
    update(acc, path.concat(head[0]).join('.'), (n) => (Array.isArray(head[1]) ? [] : {}));

    //recurse with one deeper level
    return exportContractFormatter(
      [...valueFormatted, ...tail],
      exportContractConverter,
      acc,
      [...path, head[0]],
      [...level, valueFormatted.length * -1]
    );
  } else {
    if (typeof head[1] === 'object' && head[1] !== null) {
      //empty object or array, no need to convert value
      update(acc, path.concat(head[0]).join('.'), (n) => (Array.isArray(head[1]) ? [] : {}));
    } else {
      //convert value
      update(acc, path.concat(head[0]).join('.'), (n) => {
        return exportContractConverter(head[1], path.concat(head[0]));
      });
    }
    const [newLevel, newPath] = getLevelAndPath(level, path);
    //recurse same level or shallower
    return exportContractFormatter(tail, exportContractConverter, acc, newPath, newLevel);
  }
}

 exportContractFormatter(Object.entries(data), exportContractConverter);
```

The problem is, if my object is too big (a lot of nested objects or arrays), I get the maximum call stack size error.
Something weird, if I trigger twice the recursion : the first fails, the second succeeds.

Do you have any idea about how to deal with this problem ?
Thank a lot for your help

More details :

```
const referentialData = {
    ref_1: [
      {
        value: 'xx_1',
        displayText: 'CONVERTED_1',
      },
      {
        value: 'xx_2',
        displayText: 'NO',
      },
      {
        value: 'xx_3',
        displayText: 'NO',
      },
      {
        value: 'xx_4',
        displayText: 'CONVERTED_4',
      },
    ],
    ref_2: [
      {
        score_id: 'xx_1',
        label: 'NO',
      },
      {
        score_id: 'xx_2',
        label: 'CONVERTED_2',
      },
      {
        score_id: 'xx_3',
        label: 'CONVERTED_3',
      },
    ],
};
const usages = [
    {
      referential_name: 'ref_1',
      path: 'a.ac',
      widget_name: 'widget_1',
      kind: 'simple_referential',
    },
    {
      referential_name: 'ref_2',
      path: 'c.cc',
      widget_name: 'widget_2',
      kind: 'article',
    },
    {
      referential_name: 'ref_1',
      path: 'e.eb',
      widget_name: 'widget_1',
      kind: 'simple_referential',
    },
];
const result = {
    a: { aa: 50, ab: 'hello', ac: 'CONVERTED_1' },
    b: 50,
    c: [
      { ca: 100, cb: 'by', cc: 'CONVERTED_2' },
      { ca: 101, cb: 'by1', cc: 'CONVERTED_3' },
    ],
    d: [],
    e: {
      ea: 50,
      eb: ['CONVERTED_1', 'CONVERTED_4'],
    },
};
const exportContractConverter = exportContractConverterGenerator(referentialData, usages);

export function exportContractConverterGenerator(
  referentialData: Record<string, any[]>,
  usages: Array<Record<string, any>>
) {
  return (data: any, path: string[]): any => {
    if (!data || !usages) return data;
    const _path = path.filter((item) => typeof item !== 'number').join('.');

    const found = usages?.find((item) => item?.path === _path);

    if (!found || !found.referential_name) return data;
    if (found.kind === 'article') {
      return (
        (referentialData[found.referential_name]).find(
          (item) => item.score_id === data
        )?.label || data
      );
    } else {
      return (
        (referentialData[found.referential_name]).find(
          (item) => item.value === data
        )?.displayText || data
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Without looking too deeply, I notice that you recur on `[...valueFormatted, ...tail]`.  This presumably could cause you to recur on longer and longer lists of values.  Do you have a guarantee that this will eventually shorten and tend toward an empty array?

Comment: It would probably help if you supplied `exportContractConverter`, as well as the expected output to match your input.  Without those, I think there's too much guessing involved.

Comment: @ScottSauyet
It's a way to flatten an array or an object that I meet. I add it to my tail, so yes it will cause longer recurse call but always finish on empty array. Do you need more details on something ? thank

Comment: Yes, more details, as suggested in my second comment, would probably be very helpful.

Comment: is there any condition under which your function does not recurse? it appears the fn calls itself in both branches of outer if/else block. add some logs and confirm there is a case where it can return early.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes it's done, I've added a more details section at the end of the post

Comment: @GregBrodzik yes first line of the function `if (data.length === 0) return acc;`
If I deal with non-object value, it will call the function without the first element. It work very well, but not if my object is too big.

Comment: Take a look at the object-scan npm library (disclaimer I'm the author). It's purpose build for exactly your use case / problem. I'll try and post a proper answer here as well

Comment: @vincent thank you ! But do you have any idea about how it possible to have maximum call stack ? If I use accumulator, the current function has to be removed from the stack every time because their is not compute remaining...

Comment: @vincent a lib for that? give me a break :)

Comment: @user1514042 Well, it's preference and use case dependent I guess =)

Comment: It certainly is.

Comment: @user1514042: the point of demonstrating how a library would solve a specific problem is to help make you aware of its capabilities.  We would not incorporate object-scan because it solves one particular problem well, but because we've seen a range of problems it can solve more simply than we could with custom code.  Note that vincent has posted a *working* answer to the question, making the logical assumptions about the input configuration.

Comment: That was a proposed answer so it was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much simpler code for achieving your goal, please see the script below:

```
  const data = {
        a: { aa: 50, ab: 'hello', ac: 'xx_1' },
        b: 50,
        c: [
            { ca: 100, cb: 'by', cc: 'xx_2' },
            { ca: 101, cb: 'by1', cc: 'xx_3' },
        ],
        d: [],
        e: {
            ea: 50,
            eb: ['xx_1', 'xx_4'],
        },
    };

    const isObject = target => target instanceof Object;

    const traverse = (target, process) => {
        Object.entries(target).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (isObject(value)) {
                traverse(value, process);
            }
            else {
                const set = (value) => target[key] = value;
                process(key, value, set);
            }
        });
    };

    traverse(data, (key, value, set) => {
        // can be improved by passing an array of {key, value, newVaue}
        if (key === "cc" && value === "xx_2") {
            set("xx_2_replaced");
        }

        if (key === "ac" && value === "xx_1"){
            set("xx_1_replaced");
        }
    });

    console.info(data.c[0].cc);
    console.info(data.a.ac);
```

I'd strongly recommend learning JS before looking into TS, the power of the latter can lead to confusion sometime.

Comment: This seems to be missing the point that the only `cc` to be replaced is the one inside the `c` property of the root.  The only `ac` to be replaced is in `a`.  It also makes the likely unwarranted assumption that the configuration data (`referentialData`/`usages`) is entirely static and can be hard-coded.  That would be quite surprising.

Comment: I think the owner node names are tend to be unique just check out the sample file, I agree it comes unwarranted and can be solved by using paths instead of owner node names easy change.  the static data can be passed into the processor as an argument - strange to see that comments from a 45K contributor tbh :) tonns of code and external packages for what can be solved by a 10 lines snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). A library will make your code a bit more maintainable, especially since it abstracts all the traversal logic.

1. There is complexity here because of how your input data is structured, but I'm not sure if you have control over that.
2. You won't have any issues with stack size depth since object-scan is entirely [recursion free](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#85-internals).
3. The added benefit is that you can now use wildcards and the other [extended object-scan syntax](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#4-matching) in your path selectors!
4. The library is fully documented, so it's easy to look up how that part works

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@19.0.5/lib/index.min.js';

const data = {
  a: { aa: 50, ab: 'hello', ac: 'xx_1' },
  b: 50,
  c: [
    { ca: 100, cb: 'by', cc: 'xx_2' },
    { ca: 101, cb: 'by1', cc: 'xx_3' }
  ],
  d: [],
  e: {
    ea: 50,
    eb: ['xx_1', 'xx_4']
  }
};

// / -----------------

const referentialData = {
  ref_1: [
    { value: 'xx_1', displayText: 'CONVERTED_1' },
    { value: 'xx_2', displayText: 'NO' },
    { value: 'xx_3', displayText: 'NO' },
    { value: 'xx_4', displayText: 'CONVERTED_4' }
  ],
  ref_2: [
    { score_id: 'xx_1', label: 'NO' },
    { score_id: 'xx_2', label: 'CONVERTED_2' },
    { score_id: 'xx_3', label: 'CONVERTED_3' }
  ]
};
const usages = [
  { referential_name: 'ref_1', path: 'a.ac', widget_name: 'widget_1', kind: 'simple_referential' },
  { referential_name: 'ref_2', path: 'c.cc', widget_name: 'widget_2', kind: 'article' },
  { referential_name: 'ref_1', path: 'e.eb', widget_name: 'widget_1', kind: 'simple_referential' }
];

const rewriter = objectScan(usages.map(({ path }) => path), {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ matchedBy, value, parent, property }) => {
    let result = false;
    const relevantUsages = usages.filter(({ path }) => matchedBy.includes(path));
    for (let i = 0; i < relevantUsages.length; i += 1) {
      const { referential_name: refName, kind } = relevantUsages[i];
      const [nameField, valueField] = kind === 'article'
        ? ['score_id', 'label']
        : ['value', 'displayText'];
      const replacements = referentialData[refName];
      for (let j = 0; j < replacements.length; j += 1) {
        const repl = replacements[j];
        if (repl[nameField] === value) {
          parent[property] = repl[valueField];
          result = true;
          // return here if only first replacement needed
          // ...
        }
      }
      // return here if only first usage needed
      // ...
    }
    return result;
  }
});

console.log(rewriter(data)); // returns true because data has been changed
// => true
console.log(data);
/* => {
    a: { aa: 50, ab: 'hello', ac: 'CONVERTED_1' },
    b: 50,
    c: [
      { ca: 100, cb: 'by', cc: 'CONVERTED_2' },
      { ca: 101, cb: 'by1', cc: 'CONVERTED_3' }
    ],
    d: [],
    e: {
      ea: 50,
      eb: [ 'CONVERTED_1', 'CONVERTED_4' ]
    }
} */

console.log(rewriter(data)); // returns false because no data has been changed
// => false
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: It would be nice to make this a snippet.  The only way I know to do this with ES6 modules is to put it all inside a `type=module` script tag, inside the HTML block.  But it [does work](http://scott.sauyet.com/StackOverflow/so77574197.txt).

Comment: I have a script that does it automatically, but the stack overflow api I was using broke / was down so.... Will have to try again later

Comment: @ScottSauyet fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I found the initial code hard to follow and created my own approach.  It should not  have any recursion depth issues, unless your object itself is deeper than the that limit.  If so, you have bigger problems to worry about!

I found traversing your configuration data difficult, so my solution converts it to the following `pathMap` format before returning a function which will that data and your object to create the results:

```js
{
    "a.ac": {xx_1: "CONVERTED_1", xx_2: "NO", xx_3: "NO", xx_4: "CONVERTED_4"},
    "c.cc": {xx_1: "NO", xx_2: "CONVERTED_2", xx_3: "CONVERTED_3"},
    "e.eb": {xx_1: "CONVERTED_1", xx_2: "NO", xx_3: "NO", xx_4: "CONVERTED_4"}
}
```

I have in my personal library several utility functions which make writing this easier.  `pathEntries` is much like `Object.entries` except that instead of string keys, it uses an array of strings and integers representing the full path to a node, turning you sample input into something like this:

```js
[
  [["a", "aa"], 50], 
  [["a", "ab"], "hello"], 
  [["a", "ac"], "xx_1"], 
  [["b"], 50], 
  [["c", 0, "ca"], 100], 
  // ...
  [["e", "eb", 0], "xx_1"], 
  [["e", "eb", 1], "xx_4"]
]
```

`hydrate` does the reverse, taking an array of these path entries and turning them back into an object, using the `setPath` utility function.  My version uses these by calling `pathEntries`, mapping the result into new versions based on what's in `pathMap` and in the values, then calling, `hydrate`.  It looks like this:

```js
// Utility functions
const pathEntries = (obj) => Object (obj) === obj
  ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (
      ([p, v]) => [[Array .isArray (obj) ? Number (k) : k, ... p], v] 
    )) 
  : [[[], obj]]

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})

// Main function
const convert = (
  referentialData, usages,
  mappings = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(referentialData).map(
      ([k, v]) => [k, Object.fromEntries(v.map(Object.values))]
  )),
  pathMap = Object.fromEntries(usages.map(
    ({path, referential_name}) => [path, mappings[referential_name]]
  ))
) => (o) => hydrate(pathEntries(o).map(([p, v], _, __, 
  path = p.filter(s => typeof s !== 'number').join('.')
) => path in pathMap
  ? [p, pathMap[path][v] || v]
  : [p, v]
))

// Sample data
const referentialData = {ref_1: [{value: "xx_1", displayText: "CONVERTED_1"}, {value: "xx_2", displayText: "NO"}, {value: "xx_3", displayText: "NO"}, {value: "xx_4", displayText: "CONVERTED_4"}], ref_2: [{score_id: "xx_1", label: "NO"}, {score_id: "xx_2", label: "CONVERTED_2"}, {score_id: "xx_3", label: "CONVERTED_3"}]}
const usages = [{referential_name: "ref_1", path: "a.ac", widget_name: "widget_1", kind: "simple_referential"}, {referential_name: "ref_2", path: "c.cc", widget_name: "widget_2", kind: "article"}, {referential_name: "ref_1", path: "e.eb", widget_name: "widget_1", kind: "simple_referential"}]
const data = {a: {aa: 50, ab: "hello", ac: "xx_1"}, b: 50, c: [{ca: 100, cb: "by", cc: "xx_2"}, {ca: 101, cb: "by1", cc: "xx_3"}], d: [], e: {ea: 50, eb: ["xx_1", "xx_4"]}}

// Demo
console.log(convert(referentialData, usages)(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The only other thing to call out is that the `pathEntry` format is designed to capture the full structure of the object, but your rules run equally for all elements of an array; you don't need the array indices to apply a rule.  To handle this, we filter out the numbers representing array indices before we join the path into a string.  So `['c', 0, 'a']` becomes `c.a` instead of `c.0.a`; this is the key we use to look up in `pathMap`.

Note that this is a two-call API.  We first pass the two configuration pieces, and then to the resulting function we pass our object.  If we're going to do this multiple times, this helps by letting us create a reusable function from the configuration and apply it to many objects.

---

This does not answer why your function is running into depth limits.  I have no idea.  But I didn't look deeply.  Between this and the other answers, you should be able to find something that works how you like.

Comment: forcing code into one line doesn't make the code shorter, it only makes it harder to read.

Comment: @user1514042: Line breaks are fairly arbitrary, and tastes vary.  But there is a real benefit to coding with expressions only, and not statements.  Such code is much easier to reason about.

Comment: I think we're overcomplicating things big time here. Think about it - if the reference data is geared at working with known paths only why not build the process around visiting that known paths - the rest will be ignored anyway. But I think the data has unique names already as per the sample. A lot of it is hughly subjective I agree

Comment: If that reference data is only designed to solve this problem, then yes, it's stupid overkill.  This is why I made the assumption that it's an intrinsic part of the problem.  We can solve this even easier with `return expectedOutput` and be done with it, but presumably that wouldn't help the OP much.  I think the reference data is similar.  Of course I could be wrong in this... but then I'm still answering a more interesting question!  ;-)